# How to find which files / folders are on both computers?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a folder called `documentaries` on my Linux computer.
I have SSH access to seedbox (also Linux).

How do I find out which documentaries I have in both computers?

On seedbox it's a flat file structure. Some documentaries are files, some are folders which contain many files, but all in same folder
For example:

```
data/lions_botswana.mp4
data/lions serengeti/S01E01.mkv
data/lions serengeti/S01E02.mkv
data/strosek_on_capitalism.mp4
data/something_random.mp4
```

Locally structure is more organized

```
documentaries/animals/lions_botswana.mp4
documentaries/animals/lions serengeti/S01E01.mkv
documentaries/animals/lions serengeti/S01E02.mkv
documentaries/economy/strosek_on_capitalism.mp4
documentaries/something_random.mp4
```

I am not looking for command like `diff`, I am looking for command like `same` (opposite of diff) if such command exists.

Comment: Make paper copies of the file lists and compare them.

Comment: Thanks Peter. LOL

Comment: `comm -12` is a command to find the same lines, but it only works on sorted files

Comment: @kenorb - editted. Thank you for your clarifying questions.

Comment: Same based on the filename, or including size also?

Comment: Size should be the same and can be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer from Zumo de Vidrio, and my comment:

on one computer

```
  cd directory1/; find | sort > filelist1
```

on the other

```
  cd directory2/; find | sort > filelist2
```

copy them in one place an run:

```
  comm -12 filelist1 filelist2
```

or as a one liner:

```
ssh user@host 'cd remotedir/; find|sort' | comm -12 - <(cd localdir/; find|sort)
```

*Edit: With multiple folders this would look as follows*

on one computer

```
  cd remotedir/; find | sort > remotelist
```

on the other

```
  cd localdir/subdir1/; find > locallist1
  cd -;
  cd localdir/subdir2/; find > locallist2
  cd -;
  #... and so on
  sort locallist1 locallist2 > locallistall
```

copy them in one place an run:

```
  comm -12 remotelist locallistall
```

or as a (now very long) one liner:

```
ssh user@host 'cd remotedir/; find|sort' | comm -12 - <({cd localdir/subdir1/; find; cd -; cd localdir/subdir2/; find; cd -; cd localdir/subdir3/; find}|sort)
```

Comment: What are steps needed to run this? Never programmed bash / sh. I have no idea how to create or  use shell functions - do you save it in a file and just run it? Save it in special place somewhere? Use some other command to turn it into something usable???

Comment: just paste it in the bash and press enter. to add it permanently you might want your add it to be sourced from the `.bashrc`. But how to do that is answer to a completly different question.

Comment: I don't have DIR1 and DIR2 on same computer. I have list of filenames.

Comment: Didn't work. Probably because I've rearranged my local documentaries into folders like `animals`, `economy` etc. Going to upvote your answer cause I think it would work if I was more precise and I know it takes time to find good questions & answer them.

Comment: you might still be able to use it like this: `ssh user@host 'cd remotedir/; find|sort' | comm -12 - <({cd localdir/animals/; find; cd localdir/economy/; find}|sort)` if the structure inside `animals` is the same as in `remotedir/`

Answer (score 3):

Export list of remote files to local file by:

```
ssh user@seedbox 'find /path/to/data -type f -execdir echo {} ";"' > remote.txt
```

<sup>Note: On Linux you've to use absolute path to avoid leading `./` or use with `"$PWD"/data`.</sup>

Then grep the result of `find` command:

```
find documentaries/ -type f | grep -wFf remote.txt
```

This will display only these local files which also exist on remote.

If you would like to generate similar list on local and compare two files, try:

```
find "$PWD"/documentaries/ -type f -execdir echo {} ';' > local.txt
grep -wFf remote.txt local.txt
```

However above methods aren't reliable, since one file could have a different size. If files would have the same structure, you could use `rsync` to keep your files up-to-date.

---

For more reliable solution, you can use `fdupes` which can find all files which exist in both directories by comparing file sizes and MD5 signatures.

Sample syntax:

```
fdupes -r documentaries/ data/
```

However both directories needs to be accessible locally, so you can always use [`sshfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) tool to mount the remote directory locally. Then you can use `fdupes` to find all duplicate files. It has also option to remove the other duplicates (`-d`).

Comment: shouldn't it be `grep -xFf list.txt`?

Comment: Is there a quick way to find what an option does in grep manual?

Comment: @kenorb No. I used -f for reading regex from file before. man grep: "`-f` Obtain *patterns* from FILE". Still a great answer. +1

Comment: I want to save effort. If I save local find results to a file, like this: `find documentaries/ >local.txt`, how can I modify second command to work?

Comment: @kenorb Filenames can have lots of regex chars in them. And I am not concerned with a false positive because `.` matches any character, but with filenames forming an invalid regex. Still the chance for that is also slim.

Comment: `find` / `grep` -  not a single results after two minutes, still working. I am going to try `sshfs` / `fdupes` solution later.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Maybe you did some syntax error, so grep waits for your input. Maybe re-run again. Or try grepping with `--color=none`, as if you have colors by default, grep sometimes may crash.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Don't use relative paths, since it may generate dots in the front on Linux, I can't test, as I'm on Mac, try to use absolute paths.

Comment: yes everything in `remote.txt` is starting with `./` as per your instructions. Taking a break as I have to eat.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the `ls` output of each Computer to a same folder and then apply `diff` over them:

In your computer:

```
ls -R documentaries/ > documentaries_computer.txt
```

In seedbox:

```
ls -R documentaries/ > documentaries_seedbox.txt
```

Copy both files to a same location and execute:

```
diff documentaries_computer.txt documentaries_seedbox.txt
```

Comment: Going to try it

Comment: This results in too long list and output is showing what's `different`, not what's `same`. Question is which files are same. Isn't there something like `find . -list seedbox.txt`?

Comment: Well, once you have the differences you can do a reverse grep based on that difference list.

Comment: How? Also I have no idea what is reverse grep. I always use grep like `grep -nr search_pattern .`

Comment: With `grep -v` you can invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. Take a look to the grep manual.

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea. I avoid reading linux manuals because they tend to be 1000 pages long, list every option under the sun and basically looking for something there is like looking for needle in haystack. Going to upvote your answer, go for a walk and see if someone presents a working solution.

Comment: exchanging `ls` with `find | sort` and `diff` with `comm -12` should also work

Answer (score 2):

You can mount remote folder using [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), then you can use `diff -r` to find the differences between them.

E.g.

```
sshfs user@seedbox-host:/path/to/documentaries documentaries/
diff -rs /local/path/documentaries/animals documentaries/ | grep identical
diff -rs /local/path/documentaries/economy documentaries/ | grep identical
```

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Yes, I think the folder need exists and be empty.

Comment: Thanks. Please look at last comment in Samuel Kirschner's answer. Won't even try your solution, not gonna install sshfs for something that's most likely not gonna work